# Cypress E2E tests not running in CI mode on gitlab.com

Tags: javascript, vue.js, gitlab, cypress

#### Intro

We struggle to setup cypress in the CI runners of gitlab.com. We use the default blueprint from vue-cli to scaffold the project. We tried various of different gitlab.yml configurations. Currently we run out of CI minutes because we tried so many different combinations.

We tried different docker images (from here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images/) and also followed the best practices from Crypress which we found here: https://gitlab.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-docker-gitlab/

We just had no luck getting it running. After spending hours of hours we are not sure if it's even possible to get Cypress running with the default setup from vue-cli.

We also created an issue on vue repo but it got closed, for reference you can see here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/10944

We filled out the default vue template for an issue report but since it's not a real "JavaScript" issue it was hard to properly fill it out. But we tried to provide as much information as possible. In the codepen you find our results. The HTML column is the output and the JS column is the YML file. I hope you can use this information somehow

#### Version

2.6.10

#### Reproduction link

https://codepen.io/usamahamed/pen/WNbpdPE

#### Steps to reproduce

this this the gitlab CI pipeline result including in codepen 
it give this

```
CypressError: cy.visit() failed trying to load:
We failed looking for this file at the path:
/builds/room/web/room-ui/
```

Comment: Have you double checked that this is running - localhost:4458

Answer (score 1):

Checking your `.yaml` file, I think your application is not running.

1. There is not log of application running
2. There is no build stage implementation
3. There is no start application task on the stage `test-e2e > before_script`

So I would like to suggest:

1. Check your build stage. Where you make your application start running?
2. Check your before_script, adding a step "npm ci" like this:

https://gitlab.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-docker-gitlab/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml
or
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-kitchensink/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

You should also wait for your application to be running to start testing. You can use the `wait-on` module for this: https://github.com/jeffbski/wait-on